# updating a file in specific part only in php

Tags: php, file, updates

I need to update a file using php

Sample file:

```
#Start#

No. of records: 2

Name: My name,
Age: 18,
Date: 2013-07-11||

Name: 2nd name,
Age: 28,
Date: 2013-07-11||

#End#
```

I need to edit 'No. of records' on each time I add another record on file. And another record needs to be before '#End#'

I'm using

```
$Handle = fopen($File, 'a');
$data = .......
fwrite($Handle, $Data);
```

to add records

How can I edit 'No. of records' & add data before '#End#'?

Comment: write a parser and a serializer for that file format. Then use the parser to parse the file into php structures (like arrays), then add a record and the flatten back the file and overwrite it

Comment: Hint: try to get all lines in an array with `$file_lines = file($file_name, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES)`. Remove the #End#, place new record, place #End# and edit the number of records with `preg_replace`. Finally, implode the array and return it to the file.

Comment: Standard recommendation: you should use a database instead.

Comment: I'm not getting it. Can you guys give me some examples?

Comment: @redone although I confirm with Marc B, using a database will make things much simpler. If you can selfish decide that, do so. If you are not free to choose, because the file format feeds another application, than check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of modifying the file I would parse it, change the data in PHP an rewrite the file after that.

To achieve this, I would firstly create a function that parses the input into php arrays:

```
function parse($file) {
    $records = array();
    foreach(file($file) as $line) {
        if(preg_match('~^Name: (.*),~', $line, $matches)) {
            $record = array('name' => $matches[1]);
        }
        if(preg_match('~^Age: (.*),~', $line, $matches)) {
            $record ['age'] = $matches[1];
        }   
        if(preg_match('~^Date: (.*)\|\|~', $line, $matches)) {
            $record ['date'] = $matches[1];
            $records [] = $record;
        }   
    }   
    return $records;
}
```

Secondly I would create a function that flattens the arrays back into the same file format again:

```
function flatten($records, $file) {
    $str  = '#Start#';
    $str .= "\n\n";
    $str .= 'No. of records: ' . count($records) . "\n\n";
    foreach($records as $record) {
        $str .= 'Name: ' . $record['name'] . ",\n";
        $str .= 'Age: ' . $record['name'] . ",\n";
        $str .= 'Date: ' . $record['name'] . "||\n\n";
    }
    file_put_contents($file, $str . '#End#');
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
$records = parse('your.file');
var_dump($records);
$records []= array(
    'name' => 'hek2mgl',
    'age' => '36',
    'date' => '07/11/2013'
);

flatten($records, 'your.file');
```

Answer (score 0):

In case if file is relatively small (easily fits in memory), you can use [file()](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) function. It will return array, which you can iterate, etc.

If the file is larger, you'll need to read it in the loop using [fgets()](http://docs.php.net/fgets), writing data to the new temporary file and replacing original file with it after you're done